# mySQL search multiple values in same column combined

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to achieve a simple output based on multiple values within the same table, and for it to return the Prod ID:

I have used

```
SELECT * FROM
dh_product_properties
WHERE prod_id IN (SELECT prod_id FROM dh_product_properties
       WHERE (prod_prop_value = 'iPad Mini 3' AND
       prod_prop_value = 'Silver'));
```

With the hope it will return any row (Prod_id) that has Silver, and iPad Mini 3 within it.

Here is a sample of the table:

```
+------------+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
| id,prod_id |                prod_                 |   sku    |           prod_prop_value            |
+------------+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
|       3946 | ddd329ec-4323-4381-b683-09e3e2b71b34 | Apple033 | Grade A iPad Mini: Fully packaged... |
|       3947 | ddd329ec-4323-4381-b683-09e3e2b71b34 | Apple033 | 3                                    |
|       3948 | ddd329ec-4323-4381-b683-09e3e2b71b34 | Apple033 | Retina Display                       |
|       3949 | ddd329ec-4323-4381-b683-09e3e2b71b34 | Apple033 | Finger Print Sensor                  |
|       3999 | 85799e94-e9f9-4689-95a5-2a2e742af43d | Apple011 | 32GB                                 |
|       4000 | 85799e94-e9f9-4689-95a5-2a2e742af43d | Apple011 | Bluetooth                            |
|       4001 | 85799e94-e9f9-4689-95a5-2a2e742af43d | Apple011 | TRUE                                 |
|       4002 | 85799e94-e9f9-4689-95a5-2a2e742af43d | Apple011 | Integrated Speakers                  |
|       4003 | 85799e94-e9f9-4689-95a5-2a2e742af43d | Apple011 | White with Silver                    |
|       4004 | 85799e94-e9f9-4689-95a5-2a2e742af43d | Apple011 | Built-In Rear Camera                 |
|       4005 | 85799e94-e9f9-4689-95a5-2a2e742af43d | Apple011 | 100                                  |
+------------+--------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------+
```

I also had this after reading up on others:

```
SELECT prod_id
FROM dh_product_properties
WHERE prod_prop_value = 'iPad Mini 3' AND prod_prop_value IN ('Silver') 
GROUP BY prod_id;
```

But I get all records that hold either iPad Mini 3, or Silver, rather than combined.

Can anyone please suggest a way to do this.  I know it can be done, but I don't know how search.

I tried in Google: 
mysql with AND multiple times
mysql select multiple values in one column

None of the answers really met my requirements.

**UPDATE**

If we use the example above.  Apple033 is iPad Mini 3 and Apple011 is a iPad Mini 2.  If we searched for a iPad Mini 2, White with Silver, it should only bring back Apple011.  At the moment it brings back nothing, or, every item with either White with Silver, or iPad Mini 2.

Thanks

Addy

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis in the SQL query. Was that just a copy and paste error?

Comment: in the second query that you have try using like instead of IN.

Comment: @BadAddy, show how should look the expected result

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Hiya.  It should just give me a prod_id, where the value condition is met.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need post aggregate filtering if you want all groups with both conditions

```
SELECT  prod_ FROM dh_product_properties
GROUP BY  prod_
HAVING SUM(prod_prop_value = 'iPad Mini 3')>0
AND SUM(prod_prop_value = 'Silver')>0
```

Comment: Would I be able to add more conditions.  For filtering for example using this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this query? If I understand your question correctly, you're looking to return any row that has the word/phrase "Silver" AND "iPad Mini 3". Is that correct?

```
SELECT prod_id FROM dh_product_properties WHERE (prod_prop_value LIKE '%iPad Mini 3%' AND prod_prop_value LIKE '%Silver%')
```

Knowing what you're looking for in a result will help to craft the correct query.

Comment: That is correct.  As you may notice, each row has a prod_id, this is all properties of said product.  Because they fluctuate they are in a table where each row is a property.   What I seem to be unable to do, is match multiples.